# Count non-zero numbers for each row of a second column in a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a text file in that each line words are separated by commas, like this:

```
7022122465,0,\N,,0,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022597642,0,\N,,0,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022848906,0,\N,,0,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022848906,5,\N,,0,2015-09-29 10:48:33
7022848906,55,\N,,0,2015-09-29 10:48:33
.....................................etc
```

I want to count non-zero numbers of second column using only `sed` or `grep` command in Linux/UNIX.

**Note**

Without using other commands:

```
cut -d',' -f2 < KAR_UBONA_UBONACT15_20150929_20150930_FEEDBACK.txt | grep -vcw 0
```

But I don't want `cut` only, I need to use `grep`.

Comment: You should tell us what commands, arguments, pipelines you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-c` option of grep. And you can remove all chars up to the first comma and everything from the second comma on with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^,]*,//;s/,.*//' < the_file | grep -c -E '[^0]'
```

EDIT: This `sed` command does the same as your `cut` command so you should also be able to use your original `grep` command.

EDIT2: If you want to use only one command you can use @cuonglm grp answer. If you want to use only *one invocation* of `sed` it will be a lot of work with labels in order to sum up the line count at the end.

```
sed -E -n '
    s/^[^,]*,[^0,]+,.*/+1/   # replace the lines we are interested in with "+1"
    T delete_line            # if we did not do a substitution right now we jump to "delete_line"
    H                        # we did not jump (so we did the substitution and append the "+1" to the hold space
    : delete_line            # the label, here we do nothing (silently drop the current line)
    $ {                      # on the last line we ...
        s/.*/0/              # replace the whole line with "0"
        G                    # append the hold space (all the "+1" from before")
        s/\n//g              # remove all newlines
        p                    # print the line
    }' < the_file
```

This can now be piped to `bc` or you can replace the `p` command with some complicated `sed` magic to sum up these numbers in `sed`. I believe I have heard that `sed` is turing complete so it should be possible.

If you only want to use *one program* (`sed`) but do not care to invoke it several times its much easier:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,0,.*/d' < the_file | sed -n '$='
```

Comment: here, we can't use both only one command either sed or grep

Comment: `-c` is standard, not GNUism

Comment: can u please give me answer on sed command

Comment: `grep -E '^[^0]+'` (or its shorter equivalent `grep -xE '[^0]+'` fails to match `10` or `101` or any non-zero number that contains 0. ITYM `grep -c '[^0]'`.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`:

```
grep -c '^[^,]*,[^0]' <file
```

That's only work if 2nd column is formed like integer, but not `-0`, `+0`. For more general case, see [@Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284120/38906).

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Note that it would omit 01 or 0.2 and would include `-0`, or `.0`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: right, not think about the general case, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @NarasimhaRao: It simply match the line which start character of 2nd column is not `0`, `^[^,]*,` match the 1st column.

Comment: can u please answer on sed command

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -c '^[^,]*,[-+0-9.]*[1-9]'
```

That should cover for numbers expressed as `12`, `-1`, `0e+12`, `01`, `0.0001`. But not for `0xFF` or `Inf` or `NaN` for instance, so that would still be different from the more canonical:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -v n=0 -F , '$2 != 0 {n++}; END{print n}'
```

If your input has numbers expressed in such a format.

For a `sed` only solution, you could do:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,[-+0-9]*[1-9]/!d' | sed -n '$='
```

But for a solution with only one `sed` invocation, we'd need to do the arithmetic by hand.

```
sed -n '
  1{x;s/$/0,:0123456789,0/;x;}
  /^[^,]*,[-+0-9]*[1-9]/ {
    x;:1
    s/^,/1/;s/\(.\),\(.*:.*\1\(,*.\)\)/\3\2/;t1
    s/:/,:/
    x
  }
  ${x;s/,.*//p;}'
```

Comment: Why do we need `POSIXLY_CORRECT` here? Also is there any false positive with using `print n+0` (I guess youo pre-declare `n=0` for explicit).

Comment: can you please give me answer on sed command

Comment: @cuonglm `POSIXLY_CORRECT` would be for GNU awk that doesn't recognise 0xabc numbers otherwise (would say `0x0` is not 0). `print n+0` is fine. `print +n` doesn't work with some implementations, using `-v n=0` is just clearer (IMO).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks. The `nawk` and `oawk` implementation from heirloom toolchest seems to be annoyed. With `echo 0x00 | awk '$1 != 0'`, both of them gave me `0x00` as output.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Also the sed calculator is clever, is it have a name or you have invented it?

Comment: @cuonglm, check http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc_overview.htm for real cleverness

Comment: @cuonglm, yes, just checked the POSIX spec. Earlier versions of the POSIX awk spec required hex numbers to be supported but that was an oversight as traditional implementations never did.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I have read Greg Ubben dc.sed before, but not fully got how it work immediately. Your one is easier to understand.